# Disks offline after reboot

Tags: windows, sql-server, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2016, failovercluster

Using Esxi 5.5, I created a 3 node windows failover cluster in Windows Server 2016 in order to run SQL Server 2016 Always On High Availability. Each node of the cluster has 3 disks (O/S, Data and Logs).

After installing, everything appeared to work fine. I tested the failover with several reboots etc.

I then noticed that noticed that the SCSI controller was still set at the old LSL Logic one so on one of the nodes I upgraded it to ParaVirtual using this [article](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1010398)

Now after rebooting the server, SQL failed to start. I noticed that the Data and Logs drives were both set to offline. To cut a long story short, I ended up using DISKPART and altering the san policy to set shared disks online and then onlined each disk as started [here](http://www.happysysadm.com/2010/11/disk-is-offline-because-of-policy-set.html).

This has fixed the problem but I'm wondering if I missed something else. Non of the offline disks were part of the cluster but somehow still appear to be shared somehow.

Comment: Changing a disk controller when the OS is configured is always a risky task. If it work then be happy :)